# How to set content in SlidingDrawer draggable like handle?

Tags: slidingdrawer

I want to make content in SlidingDrawer as dragable area too.
For example, I'm opening SlidingDrawer via fling gesture on handle and closing it via fling gesture on content.

What methods will I need to override? Or maybe it already exists in some libraries are?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply but I've been having a similar problem and have found a solution that should work for **static content views**. It won't work if you need to check for touch events in the content area but if you just have static text/images that don't change it should work.

I copied the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java#341) file and basically just add the code below to the `public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method. Basically it just adds the content are to the acceptable area for dragging.

```
/* Within the onInterceptTouchEvent() method (Line 341) */

final Rect frame = mFrame;
final View handle = mHandle;
final View content = mContent;

handle.getHitRect(frame);
content.getHitRect(frame);

/* Source continued below */
```

Unfortunately I haven't found a solid solution if your content area needs to be able to scroll/touch and hopefully will find something soon.